# Is there a method for firebase function, onUpdate trigger, using which can I get a info about which field is updated not the complete data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.updateEntry = functions.firestore
    .document('/customer1/{docID}')
    .onUpdate((change:any,context:any) =>{
        const id = context.params.docID;
        console.log("here"+id);
        const data  = change.after.data();
        const bdata = change.before.data()
        console.log("before"+JSON.stringify(bdata));
        console.log("after"+JSON.stringify(data));


    })
```

This is what in found in the docs and tried, but this piece of code was giving me all the fields.
**#askfirebase**

Comment: It's not possible to write a trigger that responds to only a certain document field being changed.  If anything in a matched document changes, the function will get triggered.  It's up to you to write code to figure out which fields were changed.

Comment: I am also curious why you are casting `change` and `context` to `any`.  They have specific types.

Comment: It would be very useful if could tell me the type so that I can work on it.The only reason of me keeping it to any is, the ide giving me warning, that every variable /parameter should have a type.

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, it should be picking up the types of everything automatically, given the TypeScript bindings provided by the firebase-functions module.  The APIs are also well documented.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions

Answer (score 2):

The `onUpdate()` method can perfectly be used for that purpose.
You can check if a property equals `undefined` in order to find out whether a field exists or not.

There is no opportunity to find all existing fields without iterating all possible combinations.

Here's how to check if field `fieldname` exists in the document:

```
export const myFunction = functions.firestore.document('collection/{document}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const oldValue = change.before.data();


    if (newValue!.fieldname === undefined) {
        //Field 'fieldname' doesn't exists on new snapshot, do something
    }
    if (oldValue!.fieldname === undefined) {
        //Field 'fieldname' doesn't exists on old snapshot, do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually I was looking for  just the changes in each of the fields, the fields will always be having some values, so I don't need to check for undefined. P. S :I forget to mention it sorry.